# js how to properly use block level variables with try catch

Tags: javascript

Assuming the following code:

```
   let test = dbCall();
    console.log(test);
```

Now I want to wrap the dbcall in a try catch. Which way is better:

```
let test = null;
try{
    test = dbCall();
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
console.log(test);


try{
    var test = dbCall();
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
console.log(test);
```

Comment: How about a combination of the two: put the `console.log(test)` inside the `try` body?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov the console.log is just there for demonstration purposes. There is actually other code that needs to be outside the try block

Comment: I know this, my point was that this code could very well be put inside a function and then inside the `try` body simply replace the `console.log` statement with a call to this function by passing it the `test` value as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want handle return and throw a custom error:

```
var test = dbCall();

try { 
    if(test == <dbCall_error_state>) throw "Custom error here.";
}
catch(e) {
    alert("Error: " + e);
}
```

**PS** You need replace '**dbCall_error_state**' with the return error of dbCall.

If you want throw direcly the error returned by dbCall(), conforming to the ECMAScript specification:

```
try {
    dbCall(); // may throw three types of exceptions
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof TypeError) {
        // statements to handle TypeError exceptions
    } else if (e instanceof RangeError) {
        // statements to handle RangeError exceptions
    } else if (e instanceof EvalError) {
        // statements to handle EvalError exceptions
    } else {
       // statements to handle any unspecified exceptions
       logMyErrors(e); // pass exception object to error handler
       alert("Error: " + e); // or alert it
    }
}
```

You can see detailed info about this here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Answer (score 0):

The first option is the more proper way to do this. Since the second option could leave you with `test is not defined`. I'd also make sure the code never reaches your 'example code' or the test logging in case an error was caught (so have a return or exit statement inside your catch block).

```
function makeDbCall() {
  let test = null;

  try{
    test = dbCall();
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    return false;
  }

  // only a successful DB call makes it this far
  console.log(test);
  return true;
}
```